# How can I import data via ajax into a form in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, json, ajax, forms, symfony

list.html.twig:

```
<div class="load" data-id="1">load User 1</div>
<div class="load" data-id="2">load User 2</div>
<div class="load" data-id="3">load User 3</div>


 <div class="result">

              {{ form_start(form) }}
              <div>
                {{ form_label(form.username) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
                {{ form_help(form.username) }}
              </div>
              <div>
                {{ form_label(form.email) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
                {{ form_help(form.email) }}
              </div>

              <div>
                {{ form_widget(form.is_active) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.is_active) }}
                {{ form_help(form.is_active) }}
              </div>

              <div>
                {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
                <div class="text-red">{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}</div>
                {{ form_help(form.plainPassword.first) }}
              </div>
              <div>
                {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
                <div class="text-red">{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}</div>
                {{ form_help(form.plainPassword.second) }}
              </div>

              {{ form_end(form) }}

            </div>



<script>

 $( ".load" ).on( "click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
      url:'{{ path('pages', { 'slug': page.slug }) }}',
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "id": id
      },
      async: true,
      success: function (data)
      {
        console.log(data)
        $('.result').html(data.output);
      }
    });
  });

  </script>
```

PagesController.php:

```
  if($request->request->get('id')){
      $id = $request->request->get('id');

      $item = new User();

      $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
      ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('is_active', HiddenType::class)
      ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array('type' => PasswordType::class,'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.','options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),'required' => true,'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Passwort', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),'second_options' => array('label' => 'Passwort wiederholen', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')),))
      ->add('cancel', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'Abbrechen','attr' => array('class' => 'cancel form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar close_h')))
      ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Update',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary mt-3')
      ))
      ->getForm();
      $form->handleRequest($request);


      $response = new JsonResponse(
        array(
          'message' => 'Error',
          'form' => $this->renderView('list.html.twig',
          array(
            'entity' => $item,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
          ))), 400);

          return $response;



          if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('pages', array(
              'slug' => $slug,
            ));
          }
          return $this->render('list.html.twig', [ 'form' => $form->createView()]);


        }
```

By click on a `load button` I want to load the data from the database into the form. But it is not working, no data is loaded and the error is `Ajax request 400`

Comment: A 500 response typically means your server side script is crashing or not completing. Look at fixing that first

Comment: @ChadK This code for example works   `$id = $request->request->get('id');
      $arrData = ['output' => $id ];
      return new JsonResponse($arrData);`  I see the id on the page

Comment: Well then there might be a problem in the JsonResponse you're creating

Comment: @ChadK If I click in the Ajax error Symfony tells me: `No exception was thrown and caught during the request.`

Comment: @sorry, it is now the error 400!

Comment: That's what you want, right?

Comment: No this was a mistake, I changed now the number 400 into 200. Now there is no error anymore. But still I do not see any data in the form.

Comment: @ChadK it has probably something to do with `result` class output?

Comment: So you have a form and a good response, but the form doesn't have any data in it prefilled right? Make sure you are getting the page with an id set, make sure the user at that id exists, and make sure the User class has those properties (in the form) in it

Comment: I have the solution!

Comment: `'form' => $this->renderView('list.html.twig',`has to be  `'output' => $this->renderView('list.html.twig',`

Comment: Also, make sure the User function has the proper getters and setters https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-the-form

Comment: or `$('.result').html(data.output);` has to be  `$('.result').html(data.form);`

Comment: Please answer your own question by submitting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 $response = new JsonResponse(
    array(
      'message' => 'Error',
      'form' => $this->renderView('list.html.twig', 
      array(
        'entity' => $item,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
      ))), 400);

      return $response;
```

into

```
 $response = new JsonResponse(
    array(
      'message' => 'Success',
      'output' => $this->renderView('list.html.twig',
      array(
        'entity' => $item,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
      ))), 200);

      return $response;
```

and `list.html.twig` should ONLY include the form